# Position where text starts inside a UILabel

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have an scenario where I need to know the exact position where the text starts inside a UILabel.

I made this image to try to explain easily what I need to know:
[image]

Is somehow possible to get that?!

Answer (score -2):

In order to get your label's exact coordinates, You need to convert your label's coordinate system to superview's coordinate system. You can do this using following method:

[From Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622504-convert)

> **convert(_:to:)**
>
> Converts a rectangle from the receiver’s coordinate
>   system to that of another view.

Declaration:

> func convert(_ rect: CGRect, to view: UIView?) -> CGRect

**Usage:**

```
let pos = self.lbl.convert(self.lbl.bounds, to: self.view)
print(pos.origin.x) //prints x position relative to superview
print(pos.origin.y) //prints y position relative to superview
```

Comment: I don’t think this os what OP wants. He wants to find the coordinates of text rendered inside the label.

Comment: Exactly what @Losiowaty says.